# Android ImageView's onClickListener does not work

Tags: android

I have an ImageView for which I wanted to implement the onClickListener. But when I click on the image, nothing happens. Event the Logcat does not show any errors.

Following is my import statement:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Following is my layout code for the image:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/favorite_icon" 
    android:src="@drawable/small_star"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right" android:paddingTop="63sp"
    android:paddingRight="2sp"  />
```

Following is the code in my activity which defines the event handler for onClickListener:

```
ImageView imgFavorite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favorite_icon);
imgFavorite.setClickable(true);
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(SystemSettings.APP_TAG + " : " + HomeActivity.class.getName(), "Entered onClick method");
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: @mahendraliya: Do not use `getApplicationContext()` here. Use `WhateverYourActivityIs.this`, substituting in the name of your activity for `WhateverYourActivityIs`. Also, it is often useful to log something to LogCat (e.g., `Log.w()`) rather than rely upon a `Toast` for this sort of diagnostic.

Comment: @CommonsWare: As you can see from the update, I changed "getApplicationContext()" to "HomeActivity.this".. and added a Log statement.. It still does not work.. Am I missing something which is specific for onClickListener to work with ImageView ?

Comment: @mahendraliya: "Am I missing something which is specific for onClickListener to work with ImageView?" -- no, it should work just fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I don't understand why is it not working. Do you see any probable mistake with the code which may have been overlooked by me?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I am using FrameLayout. Do you think that can affect in anyway?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using "sp" as your padding units instead of "dp"? The two will often be equivalent, but sp is scaled not just by density, but also by the user's font size preferences. You should probably have a good reason to use sp units outside of font sizes.

Comment: Struggling for hours, setOnClickListener is always not working for me. Even I tried setclickable(true), setfocusable(true), bringToFront(), etc. 

Only setOnTouchListener is workable for me.

Comment: My problem was setting onClickListener twice to some func. else by mistake.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok,

I managed to solve this tricky issue. The thing was like I was using `FrameLayout`. Don't know why but it came to my mind that may be the icon would be getting hidden behind some other view.

I tried putting the icon at the end of my layout and now I am able to see the `Toast` as well as the `Log`.

Thank you everybody for taking time to solve the issue.. Was surely tricky..

Comment: Same thing here but with a RelativeLayout.  Moving the ImageView to the end, after the View that displays the RelativeView's main content fixed the issue.  And setting the ImageView as clickable didn't turn out to be necessary.

Comment: or you can use yourImageView.bringToFront() before setting the onClickListener .

Comment: Yes! Sometimes order matters.

Answer (score 51):

can you Try this and tell me what happens ?? :

**JAVA :**

```
ImageView imgFavorite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favorite_icon);
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this,
                "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

or you should add this :

```
imgFavorite.setClickable(true);
```

**KOTLIN :**

```
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener { view ->
    Toast.makeText(this@YourActivityName, R.string.toast_favorite_list_would_appear, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
// either you make your imageView clickable programmatically
imgFavorite.clickable = true

// or via xml on your layout file
<ImageView .... android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: I tried using imgFavorite.setClickable(true); but this also does not solve the problem

Comment: i really dont understand why its not working , can you put the Code of your Activity  ? all of it plz , ?

Answer (score 13):

Actually I just used `imgView.bringToFront();` and it helped.

Comment: lifesaver! i had two views overlapping in a frame layout and couldn't get the listener to get triggered any other way. thanks!

Comment: This was exactly my problem, I think its because its overlaping another views and when you click you cant reach the view, thanks !

Comment: you save my a day.

Answer (score 5):

Try by passing the context instead of the application context (You can also add a log statement to check if the `onClick` method is ever run) :

```
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("== My activity ===","OnClick is called");
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), // <- Line changed
                    "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried using v.getContext() and adding a log statement.. But neither displays the log nor the Toast.. I don't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Add **android:onClick="clickEvent"** to your image view.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/favorite_icon" 
    android:src="@drawable/small_star"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right" android:paddingTop="63sp"
    android:paddingRight="2sp"
    android:onClick="clickEvent"  />
```

In your activity you can create a method with the same name (**clickEvent(View v)**), and that's it! You can see the log and the toast text too.

```
public void clickEvent(View v)
  {
    Log.i(SystemSettings.APP_TAG + " : " + HomeActivity.class.getName(), "Entered onClick method");
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
            "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Well my solution was another one, or let's say, the bug was:

I simply had another imageview with the same id in another `<included />` twice-encapsuled xml layout, which was found before the one that i wanted to react on the click. Solution: Give one of them another id...

Comment: Same issue occurred with me. Duplicate id.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, thanks for the Framelayout tip!
I was using two overlapped images in a framelayout (the one at top was an alpha mask, to give the effect of soft borders)

I set in the xml `android:clickable="true"` for the image I wanted to launch the onClickListener, and `android:clickable="false"` to the alpha mask.

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this one.

```
ImageView imageview1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Here is your Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For inner classes to pass the reference of activity, I usually create a reference of activity in onCreate() and make it as a member. As inner classes have access to members of parent class you can get hold of your activity and thus its context:

```
class MyClass extends Activity{
    private Activity thisActivity;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            thisActivity = this;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Regular inner classes already have access to `this` -- adding a data member for it is unnecessary.

Comment: but would't 'this'  in inner class would point to object of inner class insted the object of outer class enclosing it? or you are saying there is a way through which you can actually access instance of outerclass using this in inner class?

Comment: `MyClass.this` refers to the `this` of a particular enclosing outer class.

Answer (score 0):

I defined an OnClickListener for ImageView as an OnClickListener for a button and it seems to be working fine. Here's what I had. Please try and let us know if it doesn't work.

```
final ImageView imageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

imageview1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
             Log.i("MyTag","Image button is pressed, visible in LogCat");;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if other view has the property `match_parent` or `fill_parent` ,those properties may cover your `ImageView` which has shown in your `RelativeLayout`.By the way,the accepted answer does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening for me.

The reason is: I have used a list view with margin Top so the data is starting from the bottom of the image, but the actual list view is overlapping on the image which is not visible. So even if we click on the image, the action is not performed. To fix this, I have made the list view start from the below the image so that it is not overlapping on the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Most possible cause of such issues can be some invisible view is on the top of view being clicked, which prevents the click event to trigger. So recheck your xml layout properly before searching anything vigorously online.

PS :- In my case, a recyclerView was totally covering the layout and hence clicking on imageView was restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Same **Silly** thing happed with me.

I just copied one activity and pasted. Defined in Manifest.

Open from **MainActivity.java** but I was forgot that Copied Activity is getting some **params** in bundle and If I don't pass any **params**, just finished.

So My Activity is getting started but finished at same moment.

I had written Toast and found this silly mistake. :P

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner to android development, my issue wasn't any of these solutions. I had several problems.

Firstly, I didn't realise that you had to use the bug symbol to use the debugger to hit breakpoints.

Then I was silently getting an error in my on click listener, I was trying to pass something to a method, but the method required a float value.

However in the ide, the method was shown as unused. It wasn't until I cast the value that the method was shown in the correct colour and wasn't marked as unused anymore.

Not sure why I didn't get an error from trying to use a method with the wrong type ?

Also I had to add the `android:debuggable="true"` to my manifest to get debugging to hit breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `android:elevation="3dp"`, everything works perfectly as expected.