# OnClick function is Not firing.

Tags: android, popup, onclick

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{         
  super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);



 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
   this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 View popView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null, false); 
 final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(

   inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null, false), 
   500, 
   600, 
   true);

pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(android.R.id.list), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);    

 ImageView closeimage=(ImageView) popView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
closeimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
pw.dismiss();
 }
 });
```

I have the above code, closeimage is valid, and exists, but I click on the closeimage the OnCLick function is Not firing.

Comment: Are you sure that onClick() isn't working? Try to add, for example, Log.d("Log","click") and check it out.

Comment: I put a breakpoint it never enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see you created popView View object but into PopupWindow you inflated not your popView but R.layout.offer_popup layout.
After that you're getting Image object from popView and bind click to it. That click should close PopupWindow which has nothing to do with popView object.

Comment: I need that popView otherwise it couldn't find the imageView2.

Comment: I ment, instead of inflating layout (inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_popup, null, false)) instead of this, put there your popView. Popupwindow will have your view, you will be able to get the image, and image click should work.

Comment: Try this:
final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popView, 500, 600, true);

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any errors in this piece of code. Maybe you could test which element has focus within the view?

Also take a look at this:
[Android ImageView's onClickListener does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083641/android-imageviews-onclicklistener-does-not-work)

Kind regards,
Bram

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your onClick event is intercepted by some other view.