# Why first click on the ImageView is not working?

Tags: android, android-imageview, onclicklistener

I have read through other posts. I can't able to find the solution still.

I tried putting

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

not worked.
I have included

```
android:clickable="true"
```

not worked.

In Java code, I have included

```
  imgLeft.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                v.performClick();
            }
        }
    });
```

aside with the onClickListener().

But still it didn't worked.

Here is my rough layout structure and position of the image view.

```
  <RelativeLayout>
     <FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
           <Relativelayout>
              <LineatLayout/>
                  <LinearLayout>
                      <LinearLayout>
                          <ImageView    <--- This is the I needed to click.
                            android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_img_width"
                            android:src="@drawable/left" 
                            />  
                      </LinearLayout>
                  </LinearLayout>
              </LinearLayout>
           </Relativelayout>
        </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>
  </Relativelayout>
```

I am using setOnClickListener for handling the click event.

```
 imgLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some function here    <-- **This function triggers only after the second click**
        }
    });
```

**NOTE:**
I thoroughly checked the other stackoverflow posts. But none of them solved the problem.. is there any solution for the above

UPDATE: Original code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_image" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutConfiguration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_header_height" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_menu"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_top_icon"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.68"
                    android:fontFamily="Oswald-Regular.ttf"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Connect Bluetooths"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_tital_textsize" />

                <!-- android:padding="@dimen/menu_tital_padding" -->

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_sole"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tital_margin_top"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_leftBattery"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="Raleway-Regular.ttf"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="100%"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgLeftBluetooth"      
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_img_width"
                            android:src="@drawable/left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_leftBluetooth"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="Raleway-Regular.ttf"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Not Connected"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_rightBattery"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="Raleway-Regular.ttf"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="100%"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgRightBluetooth"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_img_width"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/right" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_rightBluetooth"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="Raleway-Regular.ttf"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Not Connected"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/menu_tital_padding" >

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleButton_connectBluetooth"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/title_img_height"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/title_text_height"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn="" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_toggle_btn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:text="Connect Left Bluetooths Only"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fl_balloon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/balloon_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/balloon_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/balloon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:fontFamily="Oswald-Regular.ttf"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Pair"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:fontFamily="Oswald-Regular.ttf"
                android:text="Configure Bluetooths"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="@dimen/menu_tital_textsize"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_top_icon"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_box"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

The id of the clicks that were performed are
imgLeftBluetooth and imgRightBluetooth. These two imageviews were triggering only after **2nd click**.

Comment: Why you using  imgLeft.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() whats the reaaon@Dinesh Ravi

Comment: is it large image or something like button did you tried with ImageButton

Comment: @murugalonger I saw in some other stackoverfow post. I can't go over it now. There it is mentioned to use the setonFocusListener along with onClickListener.

Comment: @Pavan. Its small image. No I haven't used. How to use it with imageButton?

Comment: i am not sure it will work or not but you can give try just as you have to replace ImageView with ImageButton oh you can add OnclickListenr setOnFocusChangeListener or try what ntelliJ Amiya suggested

Comment: @Pavan Its not working ..

Comment: you have too much layers on above image so i am not sure what you added  above image so it will better you post full layout

Comment: @Pavan Updated the code check above.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple  .You can try this

Just add `android:onClick="clicking"` in your **ImageView** (XML)

Then

```
 public void clicking(View v)
  {

    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Clicking On Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

**Edited**

```
    YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW_OBJ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do your Staff

        }
     });
```

1. [Android ImageView's onClickListener does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083641/android-imageviews-onclicklistener-does-not-work)

Comment: Still, I am able to click the imgView only at the second time.