# ImageView with two images and two onClickListeners?

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I have an `imageview` with two images in it:

```
    Resources r = getResources();
    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
    layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
    layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.image2);
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Now, I would like to add an `onClickListener` on each image in this `imageView`. How can I solve this? Furthermore they do not overlap.

Thank you.

--- EDIT ---

Now, in my case I have two triangles like this:

[image: Imageview with two images]

and I would like to detect the click on the triangle at the bottom left and the top right triangle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have 2 ideas to solve it, the first is have 2 imageview with different drawable and set onclicklistener for each one, the other idea is use setOnTouchListener for image view and detect the cordinates where user is touching.

Comment: Click listeners are added to entire views, not images. You could detect where you click within the view, but that'd require messing around with math that I'm guessing you don't want to do

Comment: your first idea is simple and easy to implement

Comment: Okay thanks for the fast reply. Can you make an example for the first solution? Because I don't know how to add an onclicklistener to a drawable

Comment: i have another trick for you if you know exact spot where your views display and if you are lazy to do math like me and two transparent views on top of them and set clicks to them . user won't know but its two additional views :P

Comment: click sample randomly picked from so -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083691/5188159

Comment: This is just a listener for an imageView. I know that but I have two images and would like to identify and set the click listeners to them. Not the entire imageview

Comment: What about custom view? You will create view which will contain two imageview and will have api for handling clicks on each of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `OnClickListener`, use `OnTouchListener`. Measure the position of the
touch event and use that to figure out where the click occurred.

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    long lastPress = 0L
    final long CLICK_DURATION = 500L
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            lastPress = System.currrentTimeMillis();
            return true;
        } if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            //The time between pressing and releasing has to be below a
            //certain treshold to be a valid click.
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPress < CLICK_DURATION) {
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                // Determine which triangle got clicked and then execute
                // the code that would go in an onClickListener.
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```