# ImageView setOnClickListener Not Work (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Im having some problem with Click Listener on Image View 
I try to log some text if I click on the button 
But it not work at all

Here is my code, Hope u can help me:

ChatHeadService.java

```
ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("myTag", "This is my message");
                //close the service and remove the chat head from the window
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
```

Layout_chat_head.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/chat_head_root"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Profile image for the chat head.-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_head_profile_iv"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_128"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <!--Close button-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_btn"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[EDIT] Here is the image of the layout:
[image]

P/s: I had read the similar problem in here: [Android ImageView's onClickListener does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083641/android-imageviews-onclicklistener-does-not-work)

But it seem not work for me.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It's not an error. It's just don't work, the setOnClickListener() does not recognize the click

Comment: Are you sure the Log is displaying properly?

Comment: Yes, I tested, the log worked fine.

Comment: Can u add a screenshot of the layout  ? you don't have any alignments defined for the childs of relative layout.

Comment: I edited the post, did u see the image ?

Comment: No,I mean "the log worked fine" is if i log with out the listener.

Comment: "remove chat head from the window" is simple mean that terminate the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simple than i thought

I just change from this:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

to this:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, //<-- Right here :)
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: you never posted this in your original post so you made it impossible for anyone to really answer you. best to include ALL relevant detail in your posts, enough that people can actually recreate the problem

Comment: ok, I think that information is don't need to solve this problem. However, I'll learn from it next time. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem. ImageView may be hidden / in background by some other view. Use some elevation
`android:elevation="3dp"`

Comment: its dont work for me :(

Comment: Does ImageView[`chat_head_profile_iv`] work?

Comment: no, it not work too

Comment: the chat_head_profile_iv i use setOnTouchListener not setOnClickListener. But it not work too

Comment: Sorry. No idea :(

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is not OnClickListener issue.
Just put all codes of stopSelf inside of Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).run{}
then try.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the app. Check for errors in logcat for operation bot permitted.

Answer (score 0):

ADD clicable="true" to xml

sorry the latency